# How to set up CApcCache

Tags: php, yii, apc

I want to use APC cache in function. After setting up the config

```
   'cache' => array(
    'class' => 'system.caching.CApcCache',
),
```

but it does not work. What ever I set up to cache, it always returns false.

```
$result = '121';
$cache_key = 'key_12';
Yii::app()->cache->set($cache_key,$result,300);
echo Yii::app()->cache->get($cache_key);// always return false
```

Comment: did you do a phpinfo() to check that apc is working?

Comment: yes, both apc.enabled, apc.enable_cli is set to On

Comment: make sure phpinfo() shows APC module enabled. Then try print_r(Yii::app()->cache); and see if it IS CApcCache class.

Comment: Whether Zend Optimizer enabled?  Zend Optimizer platform is not compatible with APC cache

Answer (score 0):

Dude, how much I know about apc cache, you don't need to do anything after that settings at main.php. This sets default caching to all the php codes. Now still, if you wanna do something like that, then you should try the settings like this,

```
'components'=>array(
    ...
    'apcCache'=>array(
                 'class'=>'CApcCache',
             ),
```

This may work. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers for you here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/312/getting-the-most-out-of-apc-for-yii/  That link will show you how to get APC working with Yii!
Kind regards,